# How to get Android rich text editor to compile correctly?

Tags: android

I downloaded the source code for a rich text editor from:

http://code.google.com/p/android-richtexteditor/

and the code will not compile correctly. The errors I get are:

```
"Unable to resolve target 'android-4'", 

"AndroidManifest.xml file missing!", and in the Html.java file there are 2 errors involving; 

"The import org.ccil cannot be resolved"
```

When you download the file you will need to download the version 4 of the source code because the newest versions source code has been removed. I am using eclipse version 4.2.0, Android SDK Manager Revision 20. I have installed API versions 4.0, 4.1 and many of the extras. I am pretty sure I downloaded the "classic" version of eclipse. I suspect there are 2 causes to these errors, and would appreciate input. The other threads concerning both this project and the generic errors have been unhelpful, as at least one of the threads highest ranked answers was in fact incorrect. Also, the instructions put forth were not for my version of eclipse, or were incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

> "Unable to resolve target 'android-4'"

The project was set up to be built against API Level 4 (Android 1.6), and you do not have that SDK on your development machine.

> "AndroidManifest.xml file missing!"

That should be self-explanatory.

> "The import org.ccil cannot be resolved"

That suggests a missing class, or possibly an incomplete refactoring of the code.

Considering that this code has not been maintained in well over two years, I would suggest that perhaps you consider something more modern. For example, I am working on [a `RichEditText` widget](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit) to fill the same role.

Comment: Actually, the "AndroidManifest.xml file missing!" is not self explanitory because the manifest file is included in the source code download. Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: @user1848202: No, because I have no use for that code. If Eclipse cannot find `AndroidManifest.xml`, then there is a problem in how Eclipse imported the project, apparently. That is not something anyone is going to be able to help you with very well, since we cannot see your IDE from here.

Comment: I need something that can open and read from RTF files, I was under the impression this project had some of those capabilities, but I havent even seen it run yet.

Comment: @user1848202: AFAIK, that code has nothing to do with RTF. It is a rich text editing widget. You might be able to find some Java code that can read in RTF files, then tie that into creating a `SpannableString` that applies the same formatting (or whatever subset of RTF that `TextView` supports). Or, you might find a Java-based RTF->HTML converter, then use `Html.fromHtml()` to turn that into a `Spanned` for use with `TextView` (or just use the HTML in a `WebView`, if you are not looking for editing capability).

Comment: [2012-11-23 17:01:00 - RichTextDemo] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2012-11-23 17:06:42 - cwac-richedit-master] Unable to resolve target 'android-15'
[2012-11-23 17:06:42 - com.commonsware.cwac.richedit.demo.RichTextEditorDemoActivity] Unable to resolve target 'android-15'
[2012-11-23 17:06:42 - tests] Unable to resolve target 'android-15'

Comment: @user1848202: The first one tells you precisely what to do. The second one is because the demo project was set to be built using the API Level 15 SDK, which you do not have. Either change the project to use some other Android SDK version that you do have, or download the API Level 15 SDK components. And `RichEditText` has nothing to do with RTF files.